# Перенести базу Postgresql 9.6 в другой раздел Centos 7

Tags: postgresql, centos7

Возникла задача перенести кластер баз данных postgresql 9.6 в другой раздел на Centos 7.
Нашел инструкцию:

1. Остановил postgresql
2. Перенес содержимое /var/lib/postgres/9.6/data в /home/pgdat
3. Отредактировал конфиг /etc/postgresql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf значение параметра data_directory на /home/pgdat
4. В каталоге, где хранились базы есть файлик postmaster.opts отредактировал содержимое на
   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres "-D" "/home/pgdat" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf" это инициализация места расположения баз и конфига
5. Выставить права на /home/pgdat
   chown -R postgres:postgres /home/pgdat
6. Запуск постгреса service postgresql start

Могут быть неточности, т.к. под рукой нет сервака.
Дает сбой. Жалуется на postmaster.

Где еще что-то поменять что бы заработало?

Comment: Так вы определитесь, `/home/pgdat` или `/data/pgdat`. Куда проще перенести data директорию, а на её месте сделать симлинк. В этом случае не будет необходимости править инит систему и, соответственно, куда меньше проблем в сопровождении и с обновлениями.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.Дело не в этом. В разделе, где сейчас база не хватает места. Поэтому нужно перенести. Симлинк проблему не решит. Или решит?

Comment: Решит, отчего же. Ничто не мешает симлинку указывать на директорию на другом mountpoint.

Comment: Это попробую, но не понятно, почему не срабатывает мой вариант. Кстати, новое место в папке /home/pgdat не нужно монтировать отдельным разделом?

Comment: значит в вашем варианте что-то не так. Пути у вас вообще не похожи на centos, как нехарактерен и конфиг базы, лежащий в /etc. В centos обычно бинарники базы лежат в `/usr/pgsql-12/bin/postgres`, данные в `/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/`, конфиги базы внутри data.

Comment: Что ж, непонятно откуда вы достали postmaster.opts. Мне понадобилось немного погрепать чтобы найти его. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html сама база его не читает, а только пишет. Плюс см. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html - этот файл принимается во внимание только при рестарте базы через pg_ctl.

Comment: С путями все так же. Только 9.6, а не 12. Я же написал, что могут быть неточности в плане названия папок, т.к. перед глазами нет сервака. А postmaster.opts появился после установки 9.6. До этого стоял 9.4 и не было такого файлика.

Comment: База 1С-овская на postgresql

Comment: Симлинк решил проблему :) Только в 1С необходимо удалить базу из списка и заново создать, лучше другую. Тогда все будет ок.